# Error Changing MYSQL Data Directory

Tags: mysql

I was trying to change the mysql data directory following these [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795176/how-to-change-mysql-data-directory). When I try to restart the database with step 8:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Gets the following errror:

```
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql restart

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) and then start(8) utilities,
e.g. stop mysql ; start mysql. The restart(8) utility is also available.
start: Job failed to start
```

When I try to start the database with:

```
service mysql start
```

I get the following error message:

```
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.71" (uid=1000 pid=3703 comm="start mysql ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

after trying `sudo mysql start` I get `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Comment: The first is not an error, just a friendly tip. The second message may be caused by your not using `sudo`. What happens if you try `sudo service mysql start`?

Comment: With `sudo service mysql start` I get `start: Job failed to start` (I also restarted computer inbetween). When I was originally trying I believe I had root permissions from a prior line.

Comment: Look in /var/log/mysql/error.log to see what goes wrong there.

Comment: Last entry in the log is from when I shutdown the server before changing the data directory following the instructions in the link above.

Comment: Anything in the /var/log/apparmor folder? Something goes wrong before the server even has access to the error log.

Comment: I got it working again by changing everything back to the default. That, however, does not solve my problem of changing the directory. One important piece of information is that I am accessing the mysql database with webmin, but simply changing directories with webmin prevents the mysql databse from starting. Another issue is that the original data directory has "mysql - MySQL Server" as the folder owner, but when I follow the copying instructions I become the owner of the directory.

Comment: Ah, that may be the cause of your troubles. Do `sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /new/data/directory`.

Comment: Can you explain the mysql:mysql part of the command?

Comment: `Operation not permitted`, prints out the error message for a ton of different subfolders, does not change ownership for main folder

Comment: Is that a folder on an Ext4 or an NTFS file system? Ownership and permissions don't work the same way on NTFS.

Comment: File starts on ext4 and goes to fat32. Nothing else is on the second hard drive right now, so I could reformat it if need be.

Comment: Now changed to ext4, was able to get the permissions changed correctly but still get the same error.